# Please forgive me for this mistake/ Bitte verzeihen Sie mir diesen Fehler

Tags: grammar-identification

> Please forgive me for this mistake
>
> Bitte verzeihen Sie mir diesen Fehler.

What grammatical difference between English and German leads to the fact that we need "for" in English but no "fuer" in German for writing the idiomatic sentence of the idea?

Comment: What kind of answer are you hoping for besides "languages are different"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In German, *vergeben* **always** puts the person who receives forgiveness as the dative object, because that's what dative objects are meant for — telling who benefits from the action or has to bear the result. And the thing forgiven is the accusative object, if there is any.

All combinations are possible:

> Sie vergibt.

> Sie vergibt ihm.

> Sie vergibt den Fehler.

> Sie vergibt ihm den Fehler.

In contrast, English *to forgive* does not allow an indirect object. It always takes a direct object. Either the thing forgiven, then there is no prepositional object, or the person who asks for forgiveness, then the prepositional object tells what is forgiven.

I think this is because English cannot allow a lone indirect object as it doesn't tell apart accusative and dative case any more.